# How to set size of inactive (hidden) dock clients' tabs in JVCL Docking component?

Tags: c++builder, docking, jvcl

The only dock style in JVCL that I know that has the auto hide function (to pin the dock clients) is JvDockVSNetStyle. I'm using it but I can't set the size of the inactive pinned panes' tabs. When hidden, the tabs don't show the title of the pane, only the name of the active pane is shown. Sorry, I can't post an example image because that's my first question.

In the object inpector there is an option called ChannelOption with the ActivePaneSize property. Is there a way to set the inactive pane size so it can show its name? Or maybe there is another dock style that I'm missing that has the same functions?

I'm using C++Builder and JVCL 3.45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it by commenting out these code parts:

```
procedure TJvDockVSChannel.GetBlockRect(Block: TJvDockVSBlock; Index: Integer;
  var ARect: TRect);
var
  BlockWidth: Integer;
begin
// HERE 

//  if Block.VSPane[Index] <> Block.ActivePane then
//    BlockWidth := Block.InactiveBlockWidth
//  else
    BlockWidth := Block.ActiveBlockWidth;

<snip>



procedure TJvDockVSChannel.Paint;
var
  I: Integer;

<snip>

  begin
    VisiblePaneCount := 0;
    for I := 0 to Block.VSPaneCount - 1 do
    begin
      if not Block.VSPane[I].FVisible then
        Continue;

      GetBlockRect(Block, I, DrawRect);
      Canvas.Brush.Color := TabColor;
      Canvas.FillRect(DrawRect);
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clGray;
      Canvas.FrameRect(DrawRect);

      AdjustImagePos;
      Block.FImageList.Draw(Canvas, DrawRect.Left, DrawRect.Top, I, dsTransparent, itImage);

// HERE 
//      if Block.ActivePane = Block.VSPane[I] then
      begin
        if Align in [alTop, alBottom] then
          Inc(DrawRect.Left, Block.InactiveBlockWidth)
        else
        if Align in [alLeft, alRight] then
        begin
          Inc(DrawRect.Top, Block.InactiveBlockWidth);
          if Align = alLeft then
            DrawRect.Left := 15
          else
            DrawRect.Left := 20;
          DrawRect.Right := DrawRect.Left + (DrawRect.Bottom - DrawRect.Top);
        end;
        Canvas.Brush.Color := TabColor;
        Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;

        Dec(DrawRect.Right, 3);

        OldGraphicsMode := SetGraphicsMode(Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
        Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
// HERE (changed options)
        DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Block.VSPane[I].FDockForm.Caption), -1, DrawRect, {DT_END_ELLIPSIS or} DT_NOCLIP);
```

Comment: Your solution is just bad practice, what if down the line you update the JEDI library. Yup all of your changes will be removed and you will wonder why nothing is working. Why not assign your forms icons to determine what they are as the library intends? If your forms do not have icons by default you can set each pane an icon, `(Self.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as TJvDockVSPopupPanel).VSChannel.Block[0].ImageList.ReplaceIcon(X, ICON); (self.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as TJvDockVSPopupPanel).VSChannel.Refresh;`

Comment: Modifying JVCL was certainly my least favorite choice but the product architect wants it to work a certain way...   In the end we stopped using JVCL.

Comment: Thanks, X-Ray! It did work exactly as we wanted. And we don't plan to update JVCL in our project.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event in TJvDockServer called DoFinishSetDockPanelSize.

Within the function you create for that event you can access the size of a form using Dockpanel. There may be a way from here to set the size of the tabs.